# AWS role attached to EC2 throws error when used for statSd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, statsd

I have used the following in my config file for statsd
It worked fine when provided with access ID and access key . But iamRole fails. Any insight would be helpful

```
{
    backends: [ "aws-cloudwatch-statsd-backend" ],
    cloudwatch:
    {
        iamRole: 'role_attached_to_EC2_with_CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy',
        region: 'US_EAST_1'
    }
}







#I am being shown following error#

node node_modules/statsd/stats.js localConfig.js
4 Jul 21:55:17 - [2783] reading config file: localConfig.js
4 Jul 21:55:
17 - server is up INFO

/home/ubuntu/webapp-backend/node_modules/awssum/lib/amazon/amazon.js:67
        throw MARK + 'accessKeyID is required';
        ^
amazon: accessKeyID is required
```

Comment: Have you tried with `any` as a value for the role?

Comment: yes I did , it gave me same error.

Comment: Looks like it is passed-in via `opts` (whatever that is): [amazon.js | searchcode](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/52616265/)